# What’s a word for a motif which is being overused and became boring

Tags: word-request, translation

I want to say a [film band](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=film%20band&btnG=Search%20Images&gbv=2&tbm=isch&gws_rd=ssl) is a very boring motive for a film production company logo because every other production company uses it. Is there a single word for it?

In Czech, we call it "ohraný" which translates to "corny" by the Google Translator (which isn't anywhere close) and literally means a song has been "ruined by playing". 
It's like "worn-out" for a music, therefore "ruined". I guess I'd just like to add the negative emotion in the "commonplace".

Comment: I think “film strip” might be a better description than “film band” based on the context.

Answer (score 2):

The word you may be looking for is

> [**overused**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/overused)

which usually means *something* has lost its *effectiveness*.

Comment: So could I say: "Film band is an awfuly overused motive for a production company logo."? Thank you!